# split document based on Page number input by user using VBA

Tags: vba, for-loop, ms-word, goto

I have a document of several pages. I need to split it based on number of page supplied, by user. so following macro doing great when I run it by `F8` key(Step by step) from VBA editor, However when I try to run this macro directly, it stuck in second loop of `For x to TP/P` I guess. Don't know what is cause of the problem. I have to deal with the Headers and footers after that too.

```
Sub Pages_for_Yoho()

'Pages Update 3.0 By M.B.A.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim oNewDoc As Document
    
    Dim Crng As Range
    Dim XrngSplit As Range
    
        
    Dim DocName, Start_Name As String
    Dim TP, P, GoP As Integer

    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    Start_Name = InputBox("Write first part of File name?", "First Part", "") & " "
    
    TP = oDoc.Content.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)

ST:     P = Int(InputBox("How many pages per file?", "Number of pages", ""))
    
    If P = "" Then GoTo ST
    If IsNumeric(P) = False Then GoTo ST
    If P >= TP Then GoTo ST
    
    

    Set Crng = oDoc.Range
    
    'Crng.Select
    
    For x = 1 To TP / P
        GoP = GoP + P
        
        Set XrngSplit = oDoc.Range
        XrngSplit.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, GoP + 1
        Crng.End = XrngSplit.Start 
        
        Crng.Copy ' Error line which is caused by previous lines
                
        Set oNewDoc = Documents.Add(Visible:=False)
            oNewDoc.Sections.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
            oNewDoc.Range.Paste

        DocName = Trim(Start_Name & GoP - P & " - " & GoP & ".docx")
            
        oNewDoc.SaveAs FileName:=oDoc.Path & Application.PathSeparator & DocName, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        
        '== Progress Bar =='
        Application.StatusBar = "Separating Pages " & GoP - P + 1 & " to " & GoP & " ------>   " & Int((GoP / (TP)) * 100) & "% Completed..."
        '=================='
        
        oNewDoc.Close
        

        Crng.Collapse 0
    
    Next
    
    
    If TP Mod P > 0 Then
    
        'Set XrngSplit = ActiveDocument.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, TP)
        
        'Set XrngSplit = XrngSplit.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
        
        Crng.End = oDoc.Range.End
        
        Crng.Copy
                
        Set oNewDoc = Documents.Add(Visible:=False)
            oNewDoc.Sections.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
            oNewDoc.Range.Paste

        DocName = Trim(Start_Name & GoP + 1 & " - " & TP & ".docx")
        
    'Debug.Print DocName
    
        oNewDoc.SaveAs FileName:=oDoc.Path & Application.PathSeparator & DocName, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        
        '== Progress Bar =='
        Application.StatusBar = "Separating Pages " & GoP + 1 & " - " & TP & " ------>   " & Int((TP / TP) * 100) & "% Completed..."
        '=================='
        
        oNewDoc.Close
        

        Crng.Collapse 0
        
    End If
       
    Beep
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

*Error: 4605*

[image]

**Please point out problem in my code?**

Comment: Revise `.Visible` property. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-receive-run-time-error-4248-4605-or-5941-when-you-try-to-change-properties-on-an-unopened-document-in-word-b5e08e9c-8f2a-6dbf-adc6-b99acf09766a

Comment: @AcsErno Actually its works when I use. `Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, GoP` along with `Set XR = Selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")` BUT I want to work with ranges

Comment: See *Split Merged Output to Separate Documents* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Answer (score 2):

```
Set XrngSplit = oDoc.Range
```

At this point both `XrngSplit` and `Crng` have the same start and end points

```
XrngSplit.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, GoP + 1
```

Because you have not used `GoTo` correctly the above statement does not change `XrngSplit` so, at the next line, `XrngSplit.Start` is the same as `Crng.Start` which results in `Crng` being an empty range, i.e. it has zero length because `Crng.End = Crng.Start`. This causes the error when you try to copy `Crng`.

To fix this you need

```
Set XrngSplit = oDoc.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, GoP + 1)
Crng.End = XrngSplit.Start
```